# Why the DSolve stop responding when they solve the system of coupled three differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I try to solve a system of six couple linear PDF. I applied the Laplace transform method and with some simplifications I retain with the following three coupled ODE

```
   eq1=s^2*(1-w)*e[x] + C1*D[e[x],{x,2}]+ C2*D[e[x],{x,4}]- C3*D[θ[x], 
        {x,4}] + C4 D[θ[x],{x,6}];
   eq2=-s*a (s^2 β + ϵ1*ϵ2)*e[x] - s*a*θ[x] + 
       b1*g[x] + (1 +s*a*β)*(w*D[e[x], {x, 2}]+β*D[θ[x], {x, 4}]);
   eq3=b3*s^2*e[x]-(b2 + b*s)*g[x]-b3*(s^2*β+ w)*D[e[x], {x, 2}] + D[g[x], 
      {x, 2}] +  b3*β*w*D[e[x], {x, 4}] - b3*β*D[θ[x], {x, 4}] + 
      b3*β^2*D[θ[x], {x, 6}];
```

It is suppose to obtain a **six order** ODE in $θ[x]$ but I could not simplify this system or to solve even with the following DSolve command:

```
DSolve[eq1==0,eq2==0,eq3==0,{θ[x],e[x],g[x]},{x}]
```

it gives no response. I tried to use the command Reduce, but Mathematica gives no response too. If there is no any syntax mistakes, would some one suggests what do can I do? Thank you. In this system the only functions are $θ[x]$, $e[x]$ and $g[x]$, and all other characters are non zero constants.

Comment: Bad syntax. The equations must go in a list. However, even with that fixed, I highly doubt that a solution is possible *with so many symbolic parameters*.

Comment: Also, these are ordinary differential equations—there's only one variable.

Comment: Because the equations are linear and homogeneous, the only solution is that all dependent variables are zero unless the constants happen to satisfy specific relationships.

Comment: A list like: sys={eq1==0,eq2==0,eq3==0}?  The original system becomes ordinary differential equation  in the variable x after application of the Laplace transform.

Comment: A list like:` sys={eq1==0,eq2==0,eq3==0}?`   The original system becomes ordinary differential equation  in the variable x after application of the Laplace transform.These constant are the material constants. I put it in the form  `D[θ[x], {x,2}]=A1 θ[x]+A2 e[x]-A3 g[x]; D[e[x], {x,2}]=B1 θ[x]+B2 e[x]-B3 g[x];  D[g[x], {x,2}]=C1 θ[x]+C2 e[x]-C3 G[x]` where A1,...,C3 are constants. it is not slove also with DSolve.

Comment: I do not know why `DSolve` did not produce an answer in a reasonable amount of time.  But, if it had, the answer would be zero for all variables.

Comment: You mean If I write `eq1= - D[θ[x], {x,2}]+A1 θ[x]+A2 e[x]-A3 g[x]; eq2= - D[e[x], {x,2}]+B1 θ[x]+B2 e[x]-B3 g[x]; eq3= - D[G[x], {x,2}]+C1 θ[x]+C2 e[x]-C3 G[x]` the command:` DSolve[eq1==0,eq2==0,eq3==0,{θ[x],e[x],G[x]},{x}]` will works?

Comment: If it is not correct, kindly write the corrected syntax or what is the errors in the previous piece of code?

Comment: For the three equations in your comment above, use `g` everywhere instead of `g` in some places and `G` in other places.  Then `DSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0}, {θ[x], e[x], g[x]}, {x}]` gives an answer after several minutes, but it is enormous.  Better to use the approach in my answer below, which is faster and not as large.

Comment: Yes. But how? I don't know how can I chat here in this site.

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in an a comment above, the general solution of the coupled ODEs is zero for all three dependent variables, because the equations are linear and homogeneous.  However, because the coefficients all are constants, the equations can be Fourier-decomposed, after which the values of `k` that cause the determinant of the equations to vanish can be determined.  Only for these eigenvalues are non-zero solutions possible.

```
det = Simplify[CoefficientArrays[Exp[-I k x] {eq1, eq2, eq3} /. 
    {θ -> Function[x, θ0 Exp[I k x]], e -> Function[x, e0 Exp[I k x]], 
     g -> Function[x, g0 Exp[I k x]]}, {θ0, e0, g0}] 
    // Normal // Last // Det] /. k^n_ -> ksq^(n/2)
(* b1 b3 ksq^2 (1 + ksq β) (C3 (s^2 + ksq w) + C4 ksq (s^2 + ksq w) + (C1 ksq - 
   C2 ksq^2 + s^2 (-1 + w)) β) + (-b2 - ksq - b s) (-(-C1 ksq + C2 ksq^2 - s^2 
   (-1 + w)) (-a s + ksq^2 β (1 + a s β)) + ksq^2 (C3 + C4 ksq) 
   (ksq (w + a s w β) + a s (s^2 β + ϵ1 ϵ2)))*)
```

Thus, we have a fifth order polynomial in `k^2`, which can be solved by

```
Solve[det == 0, ksq] // Flatten
```

Not unexpectedly, the results are five `Root` functions, which are rather long to reproduce here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. I try to run this code and I got the follwing message:" Argument {E^(-I k x) eq1,E^(-I k x) eq2,E^(-I k x) eq3} at position 1 \
is not a non-empty square matrix. >>

Comment: If I copy the three equations from the question and the code from my answer into a fresh notebook, I obtain the result shown in the answer with no error messages.  Try to do the same.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but I got the message; `k q s is not a valid variable.`

Comment: I believe that you are mistyping something.

Comment: Ok, it is working now. I got three roots only for  `ksq`, what is q and what is k?

Comment: Kindly notice that: the roots of the first ordinary differential equation is five roots for `ksq`, but the second system with the constants `A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1 ,C2 and C3` are only three roots. Thank you.

Comment: `k` is the wavenumber.  `q` does not appear in the equations.  By the way, I noticed that you have four questions with answers but have accepted none of them.. Eventually, this will discourage readers from answering your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advise . I do not know what should I do to close the present question?. Should I  accept the answers?but until now, the solution cannot be used because it, for  example  still contains many `#` slots and i don't know it can replaced by what?. For the other question ; should write a comment that I accept the solution??

Comment: I do not know what you mean by, the answer "contains many # slots".  I see none.  Whether you accept this, or any, answer, is your choice.  It does not accomplish much to write comment that you accept a solution.  Again, though, that is your choice.

Comment: As you mention there are 5 roots. I got this 5 roots. Each root contains 5 terms , at the end of each term there is `#1` at the end of the first term, `#2`, ..., `#5` at the end of the fifth term.  I don't understand why or it refer to what?.

Comment: Or exactly `#1`, `#1^2`, `#1^3`,`#1^4` and `#1^5`

Comment: But the system `D[θ[x], {x,2}]=A1 θ[x]+A2 e[x]-A3 g[x]; D[e[x], {x,2}]=B1 θ[x]+B2 e[x]-B3 g[x]; D[G[x], {x,2}]=C1 θ[x]+C2 e[x]-C3 G[x]` gives three roots, two of them contains imaginary part.

Comment: OK, we can move the discussion to chat

Comment: I urge you to read the documentation for `Root` to understand the usage of `#` in this context.  By the way, the message to "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" was from the web site, not from me.

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable advises. I have read it. But until now I could not catch the exact form of any root. Would you please type one root of the fifth.!.

Comment: @Essam  Are you seeking numerical values of `Root`, or symbolic expressions?  The expressions are lengthy and not particularly informative.  To obtain numerical results, values for all parameters must be provided.

Comment: It supposed to obtain a six order ordinary diff equation in`θ[x]`  , which can be written as an algebraic equation of degree 3. When finding the roots we can express all other function in term of these roots symbolically. We find the inverse function(because these functions are in the Laplace domain) of all these functions numerically by the package GWR.